# Deploying Cube on Schema Workbench - Using Command Line

Tags: pentaho

Does anyone know how to deploy Mondrian cubes without using Pentaho Scheme Workbench UI tool? Net search reveals there is some PublishToServerCommand class that is part of SW source, but I found no examples for its use on the Net. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just copy the XML to your pentaho server, and refresh your solution repository.

The only caveat is that if this is a new data source, you'll have to modify the olap datasouces.xml file too.

Comment: `datasources.xml` is under `(server location)\pentaho-solutions\system\olap` folder. You will add another secion of `catalog`